# Factorial of a positive integer between 1-10. Issue: Works only if valid input is greater than previous input

Tags: java, validation, input, while-loop, factorial

Everything works fine the first run but if I enter a valid number between 1 and 10 that is lower than the first input, the output basically stays the same.

Inputs following the first only work correctly if they are higher than previous inputs.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab6_2{

  public static void main(String []args){

    //declarations

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    char flagContinue;
    int userOneToTen;
    int factorialInteger = 1, counterA = 1;

    //process

    System.out.println("Do you want to start(Y/N):");

    flagContinue = input.next().charAt(0);

    while(flagContinue == 'y' || flagContinue == 'Y'){

      System.out.println("Enter an integer (1 - 10):");

      userOneToTen = input.nextInt();

      while(counterA <= userOneToTen){

          if(userOneToTen <= 0 || userOneToTen > 10){

            System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter an integer between 1-10");

            userOneToTen = input.nextInt();

          }//end if

          factorialInteger = factorialInteger * counterA;

          counterA ++;  

        }//end while

      System.out.println(userOneToTen + "!" + factorialInteger);  

      System.out.println("Do you want to start(Y/N):");

      flagContinue = input.next().charAt(0);

      }//end while

  }//end main

}//end class
```

Comment: If you wants to find factorial 2nd time, set values to   `factorialInteger = 1; counterA = 1;` inside the while loop.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I have been staring at this all day and could not figure it out at all.

Comment: Just a **debug** your code to understand where is the problem. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `counterA` AND `factorialInteger` back to one in the outer 
 while loop.

```
counterA = 1;
factorialInteger = 1
```

```
    }//end while
    counterA = 1;
    factorialInteger = 1;

  }//end main
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Turns out that re-initializing counterA and factorialInteger to 1 within the large while loop fixed my issue!